# Help with nth derivatives of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

The series in question is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x-1)^{2n}/4^n$. I need to figure out its 1st, 2nd and 15th derivatives at $x=1$.

I started with determining the interval of convergence, which is $(-1,3)$ if I treat the series as a geometric series with $r=(x-1)^2/4$. This way the sum (function) of the series was also pretty simple to find: I got $s=4/(-x^2+2x+3)$.

Figuring out the derivatives is the hard part. I can differentiate the sum function and get the first 2 derivatives, but there has to be a way of calculating the 15th derivative without literally differentiating the sum 15 times... any help/hints is appreciated!

Comment: You can use the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) on $-4\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x+1)^{-1}(x-3)^{-1}$

Comment: All terms but one from your original series end up zero.  Either their degree is less than 15, and 15 derivatives remove them; or they have more than 15 factors of $(x-1)$, at least one of which remains after the derivatives, and $x-1=0$ at $x=1$.

Comment: Why is it so difficult to differentiate the series termwise? I mean, it's a power series. For example, in this case the $k$th derivative of the $n$th term is $$\frac{\left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{2n-i}\right)(x-1)^{2n-k}}{4^n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the sum as following:
$$\frac{1}{3-x}+\frac{1}{1+x} = \frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x-1}{2} \right)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x-1}{2} \right)^{2n}. $$
Define $h_1(x) = \frac{1}{3-x}$ and $h_2(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$. Then using principle of mathematical induction, the $k$th derivatives are $$h_1^{(k)}(x) = \frac{k!}{(3-x)^{k+1}},\quad h_2^{(k)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^k k!}{(1+x)^{k+1}} $$
Therefore the $k$th derivative of the sum at $x=1$ is simply $\frac{k!}{2^{k+1}}(1+(-1)^k)$.